# The maximum Value Contiguous Subsequence algorithm

Tags: algorithm, subsequence, contiguous

The input to this problem is an array `A[1...n]` of real numbers. Your need to find out what the highest value is that can be obtained by summing up all numbers of a contiguous subsequence `A[i],A[i+1],...A[j]` of `A`. If `A` does not contain negative numbers, the problem is trivial and can be solved by summing up all the elements of `A`. It becomes more tricky when `A` contains a mix of positive and negative numbers though.

For instance, for `A = [-2,11,-4,13,-5,-3]`, the solution is `20` *(11-4+13=20)*. For `A = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]`, the solution is `6` *(4-1+2+1=6)*. The sum of the numbers of an empty subsequence is `0`.

There exists a brute force solution that solves this problem in ***O(n^3)***, but it is also possible to solve the problem in linear time.

1. Design an algorithm that solves the problem described above in linear time. Present your algorithm in pseudo-code.
2. Briefly explain how and why your algorithm works.
3. Give a brief explanation of why your algorithm indeed runs in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

If we don't take any item (so the solution is an *empty subarray*), we have `0` as a solution.
That's why the rule is:

```
 When running `sum` drops to `0` or below, restart summing.
```

A bit tricky moment is while summing we run into a negative number:

```
 3, 4, 5, -1 ...
```

we can either *leave* it (and have `3 + 4 + 5 == 12`) or *take* it hoping that positive numbers will appear
soon:

```
3, 4, 5, -1, 100, 200, 300
```

to solve this ambiguity we can just memorize the best `sum` so far as a `result` and continue summing.
C# implementation:

```
private static double Solution(IEnumerable<double> source) {
  // We can guarantee 0 (for empty subarray) 
  double result = 0;
  double sum = 0; 

  // Linear: all we have to do is to scan the collection 
  foreach (var item in source) 
    if (sum + item <= 0) // when sum drops to zero
      sum = 0;           // ... restart summing
    else {
      sum += item;

      if (sum > result)  // update the best sum so far on each decision
        result = sum;
    }

  return result;
}
```

Tests:

```
// 6
Console.WriteLine(Solution(new double[] { -2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4 }));
// 20
Console.WriteLine(Solution(new double[] { -2, 11, -4, 13, -5, -3 }));
```